# How to transform value of Form.Item before submit on Ant Design?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I want to transform some values of the Form before its submission (I know I could transform the values `onFinish`, but I would like this to be automatically-ish).

I have made an example with the specific case here: https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-leakey-g0uzs?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try using Form.Item -> `normalize` prop.
[image]
https://ant.design/components/form/#API

Answer (score -2):

You could try storing user's input in the component state instead. This way you can structure your request body however you want.